# Socket connection event not firing

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am creating a simple socket io application. I followed all tutorials online to implement socket-io via Node JS. The current code worked only once and after connecting to the socket it got disconnected automatically. Since then I tried all PnC but it has not connected server side.

Can anyone please help me identify what stupidity I have done? Also I do not understand that whether it is client side problem or library problem.

## package.json

```
{
    "name": "IntellicarMaps",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Demo app showing the use of Google Maps for Intellicar",
    "main": "server.js",
    "author": "Prateek",
    "dependencies" : {
        "express"    : "~4.7.2",
        "mongoose"   : "~4.1.0",
        "morgan"     : "~1.2.2",
        "body-parser": "~1.5.2",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^5.0.2",
        "method-override": "~2.1.2",
        "socket.io": "~1.4.8"
    }
}
```

## server.js

```
// Dependencies
// -----------------------------------------------------
var express         = require('express');
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
var port            = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var database        = require('./app/config');
var morgan          = require('morgan');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride  = require('method-override');
var app             = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);


global.io      = require('socket.io').listen(server);
//------------------
// Express Configuration
// -----------------------------------------------------
// Sets the connection to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(database.localtest.url);

// Logging and Parsing
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));                 // sets the static files location to public
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components')); // Use BowerComponents
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log with Morgan
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));               // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.text());                                     // allows bodyParser to look at raw text
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json'}));  // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());

//----------
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

// Routes
// ------------------------------------------------------
require('./app/routes.js')(app);

// Listen
// -------------------------------------------------------
//app.listen(port);
server.listen(port); 
console.log('App listening on port ' + port);

//------------------------
// Socket io connection 
//------------------------
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected'); //this is not printing in console.
  socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  //socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    //console.log('user disconnected');
  //});

});



io.emit('message',{"AlarmName":"CPU_FAN_DOWN"});
```

## addForm.html(Client)

```
<script src="../lib/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost', {'force new connection': true});
    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

</script>
```

## socket.io.js in lib folder

this file is always loaded,i have checked in browser console

Comment: i have also checked similar questions in stackoverflow,but its not working after just once it worked

Comment: To connect you should only be calling `var socket = io();`

Comment: yeah,i am using the same,i think there is some problem in server side only,as default socket connection is only not firing